# How do I log calling function or class? Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: debugging, debug

we see

> Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty

in our logs

and there is hardly a trace (other then "app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 24") ...

> ERR (3): Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241
>   ERR (3):
>   Warning: include(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path=
>   many directories here)

**question**: is there a way to log the calling function or log the calling class or calling file?

This way we hope! to find out what is causing this error

Comment: show full log...

Comment: What do you mean? We have log enabled etc.

Comment: just log `$includeFilePath` before inclue $includeFilePath; line in Template.php

Comment: thanks. But won't this be the empty tring like the error statement? I mean, I would eventually be logging an empty string (See error). THis is why I am trying to find out the calling class or function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved this by adding

```
Mage::Log("Function <NAME HERE> called from: " . get_class($this) );
Mage::log(Mage::printDebugBacktrace(), null, 'backtrace.log'); //or you can even log the backtrace
```

where 'Mage::printDebugBacktrace()' was grabbed from here

http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/utilizing-debug_backtrace-function-for-magento-debugging/

This way we had some more info to go by ...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem once in a while, the problem is always a missing template file. Unfortunately the error messsage with its printed stack trace does not reveal much, so you don't know which template file actually is missing.

If you use XDebug, you can set a conditional breakpoint at /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php line 241 with the condition `$includeFilePath==''` and then when it halts, inspect the `$filename` variable to see which file should be included. Looking at the variables in the call stack will show you more information about the block and where it is in the layout.

However, this is still annoying, so I started to write a developer module for more meaningful error messages: https://github.com/schmengler/DebugErrors "Filename cannot be empty" is the first error it covers.